# Sending Email through tor for android

Tags: configuration, android, email, javascript

I recently losty computer and am unable to check email with from onion network. I found tor tor which enables me to browse the dark web however  I am unable to send and receive messages. I found ones that claim to work in Android however they do not access onion servers or require JavaScript enaed.  Is there a way send and receive email through tor on my Samsung galaxy at 2017?

Answer (score 0):

you didn't tell us what you use to send emails? webmail or some local software? webmail roundcube will ask you for javascript, squirrelmail will not ask you for javascript. android orfox and orbot are not "guilty" if your mail provider demands javascript. if you use gmail, you can switch to old html version. but I didn't try it long time, I think it is possible. if you use any local software on Android to send emails, we need to know which one.

Answer (score 0):

K-9 is an Android open source mail client. I've edited the code, so onion addresses are currently supported in my source. You may check the details in my blog:
[Connecting to Hidden Mail Server using Android](https://mstajbakhsh.ir/my-contribution-in-k9-android-mail-client/)

Additionally you can check my Pull Request in K-9's source at:
https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/pull/3889

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it totally depends on the mail **server** configuration, not a client: you can utilize even a builtin one through Orbot with total proxification enabled. If the server is set up properly - it can even have an onion address! So - on the client side you need **just** a working email client, that's it! Everything else depends on server